# how to apply CSS to this jQuery function's results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want the following search results to be returned in an unordered list with this class designation "my-results". I cannot figure out where in the code below to apply my class designation.

The HTML is dynamically generated. There is no static element like this pre-existing on the page:

```
<ul class="my-results"></ul>
```

Here is the function I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cache = {};
    $( '#top-search-input' ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            if (request.term in cache) {
                response(cache[request.term]);
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://example.com/search", 
                data: {
                    q: "*" + request.term + "*",
                    type: "Search",
                    view: "json",
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function( data ) {
                    if (data.length) {
                        cache[request.term] = data;
                    }
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            window.location = ui.item.url;
        },
    }).data( 'ui-autocomplete' )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var elemHTML = $('<a></a>').attr('href', item.url);
            elemHTML.append('<span class="thumbnail"><img src="' + item.thumbnail + '" /></span>');
            elemHTML.append('<span class="title">' + item.title + '</span>');
        return $( '<li class="ui-menu-item" >' )
            .append( elemHTML )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

after last line of your code set:

```
$("ul").addClass("my-results");
```

Comment: You said, "after last line of your code set." I'm not sure which line you mean. It doesn't seem like it could go outside the function body. Thanks for clarifying for me...

Comment: The identetion is to hard to follow. Try after .appendTo( ul );

Comment: I suggest you, to change the name from my-results to my_results

Comment: I will change the name. But if I add this after `.appendTo( ul );` I don't see how it can work because anything after a `return` statement in a function has no effect. (I don't know javascript well, but that rule should apply in any language.)

Comment: Ok so try to continue your code like this: .appendTo( ul ).parent().addClass("my_results");

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.my-results').html('your li list code here');
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED :replace internal part of

```
 data( 'ui-autocomplete' )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
```

to this:

```
var elemHTML = $('<a></a>').attr('href', item.url);
        elemHTML.append('<span class="thumbnail"><img src="' + item.thumbnail + '" /></span>');
        elemHTML.append('<span class="title">' + item.title + '</span>');
       // alert($('body').find('ul').hasClass("my_result"));
        if($("ul").hasClass("my_result")){
          //  console.log('if');
            return $('ul').append($( '<li class="ui-menu-item" >' )
                    .append( elemHTML ).append('</li>'));
        }else{
            // console.log('else');
        return  $('<ul class="my_result" >').append($( '<li class="ui-menu-item" >' )
                .append( elemHTML ).append('</li>')).appendTo('body');
        }
```

it should work for you.

Comment: The class "my-results" is not already defined anywhere in HTML. The HTML returned by this function is the only HTML that will have this class designation.

Comment: how you will append to something which does not exist on the page.better use createElement statement to create ul then append results to this and then append this ul to body.

Comment: i'll suggest better have ul hidden on the page when you have result then only append and show the results.

Comment: i'm saying in your dom there will not be any ul so how you will append to it.

Comment: Exactly! That was my point. Your answer proposes that I append to something that doesn't exist. I was hoping you could give me an answer that will work. The ul is dynamically generated like in this demo: http://search-autocomplete.myshopify.com/

Comment: try this. change your ul based on your requirement.